# Как работает PrintPreviewDialog?

Tags: c#, winforms

Я загружаю в `RichTextBox` текст из файла. как сделать предварительный просмотр используя `PrintPreviewDialog`?

Делаю так:

```
private void предварительныйПросмотрToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
    printPreviewDialog1.Show(); 
}
```

но в открывающемся окне не отображается содержимое ричБокса, почему?

Answer (score 1):

**1. Как работает**
Как и другим диалогам связанным с печатью GDI, для работы `PrintPreviewDialog` необходим объект `PrintDocument`. При вызове диалога, происходит вызов метода `Print()` для текущего объекта `PrintDocument` связанного с диалогом, но сформированное изображение отдается не принтер, а на экран. После нажатия на кнопку **печать**, диалог меняет `PrintController` у `PrintDocument` и изображение отправляется на принтер, выбранный ранее или установленный по-умолчанию.

**2. Почему ни чего не показывает**
Выше я упоминал метод `Print()`. Для его работы необходимо подписаться на событие `PrintPage` объекта `PrintDocument`, и в обработчике, сформировать требуемое для печати изображение. Формирование изображения производится стандартным для GDI способом, через объект `Graphics` который передается в аргументах события.

**3. Печать содержимого RichTextBox**
Эта задача не имеет простого решения, особенно если требуется сохранить стили, разметку, встроенные изображения и т.д. формата RTF. Специалисты Microsoft в 2007 году предложили создать кастомный контрол унаследованый от оригинального RichTextBox. Подробная инструкция **[How to print the content of a RichTextBox control by using Visual C# .NET or Visual C# 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/812425)**. Более короткого и красивого решения данной задачи для WinForms мне обнаружить не удалось. Возможно в WPF эта задача решается проще.