# Печать из макета в .net (десктопные приложения)

Tags: c#, .net

Доброго времени суток!

Какие приёмы используются, при разработке десктопных приложений под .net,
для формирования документов из макета, с последующей печатью. По аналогии с 1С.

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема? Макет создать? Заполнить данными? Напечатать? Какой выходной формат нужен? А приемы стандартные. создаем макет, заполняем данными, печатаем. Как именно выполнить каждый шаг зависит от очень многого: выбора БД, формата выходного файла, выбора UI-фреймворка и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Видимо, вопрос не совсем понятен изначально... Вот в 1С есть стандартные макеты для печати. В .net ничего похожего не видно. Ну, для asp.net, там понятно, что в html всё делается. Так вот и хотелось бы узнать, дабы не изобретать велосипед, какими решениями чаще всего пользуются для генерации документа из макета, и последующей печати под .net. html, XAML, или ещё что то?

Comment: Вообще, тема печати в .net почти не освещена. Как будто и не надо никому.

Comment: хм... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/489414/198316, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/488883/198316, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/489291/198316, это только мои ответы, но я их тоже не из воздуха брал, там и ссылки на статьи и документацию есть. Все таки попробуйте конкретизировать вопрос. Я например, предпочитаю формировать PDF, а уже потом его печатать любым способом, для этого тоже есть не мало способов.

Comment: Ну и не стоит забывать, что 1С - узко-специализированный продукт, за рамки его шаблонов выйти довольно проблематично. В .NET наоборот, делай что хочешь, но вся ответственность за выбор решения на разработчике.

Comment: Что то подобное уже видел. Но это всё как то низкоуровнево. По сути, в ручную придётся всё рендерить. Хотелось бы или из RichText в RTF или из XAML. А из PDF не очень удобно - требуется внешняя программа.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69712/discussion-between-rdorn-and-kisssko).